# jquery special event hoverintent on accordion not working in jquery 1.7

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/tgWKZ/

This worked in the older version of jQuery. Only thing that is stopping me from upgrading the new version right now. Anyone know a solution to get this working with jquery 1.7?

What's odd is that hover is opening the sections, there is just no delay?

Here is the example of it working with jquery 1.6.2 http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/hoverintent.html

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out for awhile now, but the documentation for jquery.special.event is limited to blog posts about it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tgWKZ/9/ shows that the event just isn't being bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in jquery core, it's been patched in the latest build and will be in 1.7.1

here is a thread discussing it 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-special-event-hoverintent-on-accordion-not-working-in-jquery-1-7

and here are a couple of alternatives:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmethvin/8WSVS/

and

```
_this.$menu.tabs({ event: "click"})
            .find(".ui-tabs-nav a[href]")
            .hoverIntent( 
                function() 
                {
                  $(this).click();
                },
                function() {}
            );
```